# Can we click custom listview items and make different actions on App Widget

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-appwidget

I have an App Widget and custom listview on it and listview contain one `textview` and two `buttons`. When I click listview items I can only make one action like toast message. How can I click listview's items and make different actions like clicking one listview's button and toasting message and clicking other listview's button and toasting different message on App Widget?